# Not able to turn on/off bluetooth radio setting using Win32 API (Bluetoothapis.h)

Tags: c#, winapi, bluetooth

I need to turn ON/OFF the Bluetooth radio in Windows 10 settings. I tried the [Bluetoothapis.h API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bluetoothapis/) in which:

- [BluetoothGetRadioInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bluetoothapis/nf-bluetoothapis-bluetoothgetradioinfo) function returns my Bluetooth radio name, but I could not find any Set method there.
- [BluetoothSetServiceState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bluetoothapis/nf-bluetoothapis-bluetoothsetservicestate) function returns `ERROR_SERVICE_DOES_NOT_EXIST` error, I am not able to find the particular Bluetooth GUID.

I tried both of these functions in native C++ & also in C#, and I need certain clarifications:

1. Is there any specific API to change the Bluetooth radio settings?
2. In `Bluetoothapis.h` API, is there any Set method to change the Bluetooth radio?
3. How do I find the Bluetooth service GUID?

Comment: You must use WinRT API to do that. Note that you can do it only if your application has the same "bits" as the OS. It means that on 32 bit OS your app must be 32 bit and on 64 bit OS your app must be 64 bit (with 32 bit app on 64 bit OS it will not work).

Answer (score 0):

The `BluetoothSetServiceState` function enables or disables services for a Bluetooth device. As far as I'm concerned, the function is used to connect/disconnect the Bluetooth. If you want to turn on/off the Bluetooth radio, I suggest you try to use the Windows Runtime API [`Windows.Devices.Radios`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.radios?view=winrt-18362). The [`RadioState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.radios.radiostate?view=winrt-18362) enum can be set to On, Off, Disabled, or Unknown.

I suggest you refer to the sample:

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/RadioManager

Comment: @Joneselas N Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us. Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.